# ANTLR:non-LL(*) decision due to recursive rule

Tags: antlr, grammar

I have tried to resolve this problem(removing the backtrack in my grammar) but i did not succeed,this is my grammar code: i have the problem in the "**condition**" rule

```
    grammar Sample3;

options {
  language = Java;
  output=AST;
  ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}
tokens{
    NEGATION;
}
@header {
  package com.tuto.antlr;
}

@lexer::header {
  package com.tuto.antlr;
}
program
    :   conditions EOF!
    ;
conditions
    :   condition (('and'^ | 'or'^)condition)*
    ;
condition
    :    relation (('and'^ | 'or'^)relation)*

    ;
relation
    :   expression(('='^ | '<'^ | '>'^  | '<='^ | '>='^ | '<>'^ )expression)+ 
    //| '('expression(('='^ | '<'^ | '>'^  | '<='^ | '>='^ | '<>'^ )expression)+')'
    ;

term
    :   POSITIVE_NUMBER
    |   IDENT
    |   '('! expression ')'!
    ;   
unary
    :   ('+'! | negation^ )* term
    ;
negation
    :   '-' -> NEGATION 
    ;
multi
    :   unary (('*'^ | '/'^ | '%'^)unary)*
    ;   
expression
    :   multi(('+'^ | '-'^ )multi)*
    ;

IDENT:('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')*;
POSITIVE_NUMBER:'0'..'9'+ ('.' ('0'..'9')+)?;
//NEGATIVE_NUMBER:'-''0'..'9'+ ('.' '0'..'9'+)?;
WS : (' '|'\n'|'\r'|'\t')+ {$channel = HIDDEN;};
COMMENT:'//' .* ('\n' | '\r') {$channel = HIDDEN;};
MULTI_COMMENT : '/*' .* '*/' {$channel = HIDDEN;} ;
```

I tried to add backtrack=true in option but nothing...
can any one help me,please.Thanks in advence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
conditions
    :   relation (('and'^ | 'or'^)conditions)*
    ;
```

That will match any list of relations. Delete 'condition' production. I will recommend you to check the Dragon's book.